# Solving non-linear equations in R with optimal inital values

Tags: r, nonlinear

I am using the `rootSolve` package in R to estimate parameters of non-linear equations. The basic formula is `OEP=1-exp(-(1-CDF(x))*numda)`. CDF(x) follows a Gamma distribution. I have three pairs of values of (x, OEP), which gives me three equations with three unknown: alpha, theta, numda.

Here is my code:

```
ga1<-function(x) {
 F1=(1-pgamma(5000000,shape=x[1],scale=x[2]))*x[3]-0.223
 F2=(1-pgamma(20000000,shape=x[1],scale=x[2]))*x[3]-0.069
 F3=(1-pgamma(40000000,shape=x[1],scale=x[2]))*x[3]-0.025
c(F1=F1, F2=F2,F3=F3)}
```

The problem is that when I use `multiroot` function, I would need to input initial values. I have been trying different values but it either return errors or wrong values with warning messages:

```
Warning messages: 
    1: In stode(y, time, func, parms = parms, ...) :
       error during factorisation of matrix (dgefa); singular matrix 
    2: In stode(y, time, func, parms = parms, ...) : steady-state not reached
```

What is the best way to guess the optimal initial values. Or is there any other method to estimate the parameters?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's a `numda`?